# How to insert a decimal value in DB?

Tags: java, db2, decimal

I am trying to insert a decimal no in db2 using the normal insert expression. After the execution of the query when i do a select for the particular inserted value , i get it as a result.

But when i go inside the table schema and look for the inserted value for the particular element, i see that it is empty. Now while trying to retrieve the same value via java it gives me an empty string.

The table is like this : with two decimal(18,2) fields.

```
insert into TEST values (153, 'test', 'test', 1, 1, 1.11, 1.11)
```

The select query :

```
Select * from TEST
```

gives me the actual value entered.
But when i go inside the table schema, i dont find the entered inputs for the decimals.

Can some one tell me where i am going  wrong ?

Comment: Is it only decimals which are giving you this problem? You can insert everything else just fine?

Comment: yes other inserts are fine .

Comment: What happens if you commit, close the connection, and then reconnect and try the select?

Comment: I have done those, but the end result has always been the same .

Comment: Do you still get the decimals back after a select in that case?

Comment: yes i did, strangely enough the select is giving me back the decimals. Oh God, this is killing me .

Comment: show us your java code used to retrieve the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a [java.math.BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) field, and put your double or float value into that field.

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(1.11);
```

The BigDecimal field (value) will go into the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

without seeing the code, i suspect, that you made a rollback instead of a commit?
or you use not the correct isolation level (READ_UNCOMMITED)